# How do I get an SSL* from Boost.ASIO?

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I'm implementing a client SSL connection via Boost.ASIO. According to the reference book I'm using, I need to call `SSL_get_verify_result` to ensure that everything's okay with the server certificate. Unfortunately, it takes a pointer to an `SSL` structure, and I have no idea how to get that out of ASIO.

I've tried using the `impl()` function on my `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>` object, but the compiler complains that it returns something else.

There *must* be a way to get that information. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. The structure that it says `impl()` returns is `boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_stream_service::impl_struct*`. I didn't expect it to be documented, but I finally searched for it in desperation and discovered otherwise. Even better, it contains a pointer to the `SSL` structure I need, as well as the OpenSSL `BIO` structure and some sort of buffer.

Comment: impl_struct is defined here: /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_stream_service.hpp

Answer (score 0):

ASIO has a native method for doing this: call `set_verify_mode` on the ssl context.

The impl() method returns an SSL_CTX*, but you shouldn't depend on that.

Comment: Yes, the `impl()` method on the context returns an `SSL_CTX*`. The one on the ssl::stream returns something else.

Comment: And `set_verify_mode` is only good for very basic checks. It isn't sufficient for security.